# Why are radiated emissions standards for consumer electronics different from industrial?

Tags: emc, fcc, emissions

Why are radiated emissions standards for consumer electronics different from industrial?

[image]

Source:??

Comment: Do you have source for that image?

Comment: Probably because consumers aren't running enormous plants with lots of heavy equipment everywhere so they need a bit more leeway.

Answer (score 3):

Because consumers have more devices like TV's and radios and they are more susceptible to noise than industrial or commercial equipment (and more likely to complain). Industrial environments are especially noisy (especially any with large switching voltages or large power feeds). This makes it easier for me to pass FCC standards with the products I make because I register them as class A.

Wiki:

> The emission limits for Class B devices are about 10 dB more
> restrictive than those for Class A devices since they are more likely
> to be located closer to radio and television receivers.
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15

Comment: >>>   (and more likely to complain)       THIS       Add to it, the consumer device limits in Europe are even more restrictive, presumably because residences are more closely packed together than in the US

Answer (score 0):

Industrial equipment costs more and has the luxury of higher cost EMI protection immunity when needed. They  can also tolerate alternative solutions to relocate the expected high noise environments of unintentional radiation away from receivers or visa versa.  Home dwellers are less likely to have these professional solutions.

Consider also arc welders don’t have any emission requirements and are very noisy but contained inside metal wall structures when required.